# Nginx reverse proxy - remove "Secure" from cookies

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cookies

For the sake of **development** I need to make NGINX drop "Secure" flag from cookie headers.

`Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzz; Path=/; Secure`

should become

`Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzz; Path=/;`

For each Set-Cookie header. I am creating a reverse-proxy configuration to decouple development server from the UI and since upstream is running behind HTTPS while NGINX is running on plain HTTP, browser refuses to send cookies back.

Comment: Should be easier to get an ssl certificate.

Comment: You're right, this is what I'm doing now, but my internal perfectionist told me to ask this question :)

Answer (score 4):

Since nginx 1.19.3 you can use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags. For example:

```
proxy_cookie_flags some_cookie nosecure;
```

To remove the `Secure` flag from all cookies:

```
proxy_cookie_flags ~ nosecure;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old question, but there is no answer here and I couldn't find fine solution for the same problem.

So I forked `nginx_cookie_flag_module` module and changed it to `nginx_unsecure_cookie_module`:
https://github.com/yumauri/nginx_unsecure_cookie_module

I'm frontend developer, my C/C++ knowledges are super low, but looks like it is working in my tests :) So I reckon it is good enough for development reasons.